# Cloudbees Content-Type not working properly

Tags: http-headers, playframework-1.x, cloudbees

I've noticed that in some cases when I use different SEO tools the text on my page appears as a whole bunch of random characters. I believe this must be due to the charset not being set properly. I want to make sure the proper charset is being used and the fact that some sites aren't reading it properly makes me think there is an issue with the http headers.

I checked the headers on all the sites I host on Cloudbees and the Content-Type Header value is always "text/html; charset=utf-8;charset=utf-8". I'm not sure if having that double value is causing issues.

Would that be an issue with the Ingnx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific app that shows this? I tried curl -I on various app URLs and didn't see this.

EDIT: I have seen this in other play 1.x war deployed apps - even without nginx in the loop.

This is a bug with play1: https://bugs.launchpad.net/play/+bug/337472 but it looks like it should have been fixed some time ago.

Play2 is now available on CloudBees, BTW.

Comment: curl -I http://www.grizzlyocean.com/

shows:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;charset=utf-8

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong in my app?

Comment: Odd - I just saw it with another play1 app of mine - and even if I go direct to the app - it still does it. Only play1 apps though - other apps are fine - so something about the play war seems broken ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to get around to upgrading then.